# How to print results in Mosel

Tags: mosel, xpress-optimizer

I am attempting to create a mosel model that takes data from an excel file and concerns energy demand for 20 regions.
Each region has 3 possible alternatives corresponding to the kind of energy centrals we're considering in the model and a maximum of capacity.
Centrals differ for variable costs per mw and our goal is to cover the overall demand of the regions by minimizing total costs.
Each region has a constraint regarding the quantity of energy that can produce.
When I try to print the results the final matrix (X) it appear in that way:
"[0x7fd85a85ea70,0x7fd85a85ea80,0x7fd85a85ea90,0x7fd85a85eaa0,0x7fd85a85eab0,0x7fd85a85eac0,0x7fd85a85ead0,0x7fd85a85eae0,0x7fd85a85eaf0,0x7fd85a85eb00,0x7fd85a85eb10,0x7fd85a85eb20,0x7fd85a85eb30,0x7fd85a85eb40,0x7fd85a85eb50,0x7fd85a85eb60,0x7fd85a85eb70,0x7fd85a85eb80,0x7fd85a85eb90,0x7fd85a85eba0,0x7fd85a85ebb0,0x7fd85a85ebc0,0x7fd85a85ebd0,0x7fd85a85ebe0,0x7fd85a85ebf0,0x7fd85a85ec00,0x7fd85a85ec10,0x7fd85a85ec20,0x7fd85a85ec30,0x7fd85a85ec40,0x7fd85a85ec50,0x7fd85a85ec60,0x7fd85a85ec70,0x7fd85a85ec80,0x7fd85a85ec90,0x7fd85a85eca0,0x7fd85a85ecb0,0x7fd85a85ecc0,0x7fd85a85ecd0,0x7fd85a85ece0,0x7fd85a85ecf0,0x7fd85a85ed00,0x7fd85a85ed10,0x7fd85a85ed20,0x7fd85a85ed30,0x7fd85a85ed40,0x7fd85a85ed50,0x7fd85a85ed60,0x7fd85a85ed70,0x7fd85a85ed80,0x7fd85a85ed90,0x7fd85a85eda0,0x7fd85a85edb0,0x7fd85a85edc0,0x7fd85a85edd0,0x7fd85a85ede0,0x7fd85a85edf0,0x7fd85a85ee00,0x7fd85a85ee10,0x7fd85a85ee20]"
I attach code thank you.

```
uses "mmxprs","mmsheet"!optimization library, Excel library

! Declaration of parameters used in the model
parameters
  FileTo="mmsheet.xlsx:noindex;last.xlsx" !Excel file with the input data
end-parameters

setparam("XPRS_VERBOSE",true);        !Activate xpress verbose.
setparam("XPRS_MAXTIME", 60)        !Setting maximum search time to 1 hour=3600 seconds


declarations
  N:integer;    !Number of REGIONS to consider
  Cent:integer; !DIFFERENT CENTRALS
  totdemand: integer;
end-declarations


initializations from FileTo
  N as "[Regions$A1]"         !Read this value from the Excel file in sheet CityNumber cell A1
  Cent as "[Centrals$A1]"
  totdemand as "[Demand$B23]"
end-initializations

declarations
    Regions=1..N;
    Centraltype= 1..Cent;
    maxproductible: array(Regions) of real;  
    Demand: array(Regions) of real;                 !expected demand from each city
    costtype: array(Centraltype) of real;
    RegionName: array(Regions) of string;!city names
    !NCentraltype: array(Centraltype) of string;
    maxcapacity: array(Regions,Centraltype) of real;
    X: array(Regions,Centraltype) of mpvar;       !capacity produced
    !y:array(Centrals,Regions) of mpvar;    !binary variable that assigns warehouse to city of customers in MODEL 0
                                           !continuous variable that count homw many coustomeres of a city are served by a warehouse
ObjectiveFunction: linctr;
end-declarations

initializations from FileTo
    !Distance as "[Distance$B3:U22]"
    Demand   as "[Demand$B1:B20]"
    RegionName as "[Demand$A1:A20]"
    !NCentraltype as "[Centrals$G9:G11]"
    costtype as "[Centrals$F3:F5]"
    maxproductible as "[Demand$F1:F20]"
    
end-initializations

procedure Modelllll
    totcost:=sum(r in Regions,C in Centraltype) X(r,C)*costtype(C)
    forall (r in Regions, C in Centraltype) X(r,C) <= maxcapacity(r,C)
    forall (r in Regions) sum(C in Centraltype) X(r,C)<= maxproductible(r)
    forall (r in Regions) sum(C in Centraltype) X(r,C) >= totdemand
    minimise(totcost)
end-procedure


! Print out the solution
 writeln("Total setup times: ", getobjval)
 forall(r in Regions,C in Centraltype) 

end-model
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot the code that prints out `X`. The code you posted only prints the objective value. Can you please update your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, `X` is an array of `mpvar`. According to the [documentation of write() and writeln()](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mosel/mosel_lang/dhtml/write.html), for such an array only the memory addresses of the elements are printed. This is why you see all those hexadecimal numbers.

In order to see the actual value of a decision variable, you have to access the `.sol` property of the variable and for example

```
forall(r in Regions,C in Centraltype)
  writeln(X(r,C).sol)
```